# Cannot get program to run. (Javascript, HTML, CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a simple text based rpg for my little nephew. I followed along with a youtube tutorial and for some reason I cannot understand, the program won't run. I've gone over the code in all three files several times for typo's and anything obscure that shouldn't be there. However, I am stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const textElement = document.getElementById("text")
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById("option-buttons")


let state = {}

function startGame(){

    state = {}
    showTextNode(1)

}

function showTextNode(textNodeIndex){
    const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex)
    textElement.innerText = textNode.text
    while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild){
        optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
    }

    textNode.options.forEach(option => {
        if(showOption(option)){
            const button = document.createElement("button")
            button.innerText = option.text
            button.classList.add("btn")
            button.addEventListener("click", () => selectOption(option))
            optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button)

        }
    })
}

function showOption(option) {
    return option.requiredState == null || option.requiredState(state)
}


function selectOption(option) {
    const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
    state = object.assign(state, option.setState)
    if (nextTextNodeId <= 0){
        return startGame()
    }
    state = Object.assign(state, option.State)
    showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}

const textNodes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "You wake up in a strange place and you see a jar of blue goo near you.",
        options: [
            {
                text: "Take goo",
                setState: {bluegoo: true},
                nextText: 2
            },
            {
                text: "Leave the goo",
                nextText: 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "You venture forth in search of answers to where you are when you come across a merchant.",
        options:[ 
            {
                text: "Trade the goo for a sword.",
                requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.bluegoo,
                setState: {bluegoo: false, sword: true },
                nextText: 3
        },
        {
            text: "Trade the goo for a shield.",
            requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.bluegoo,
            setState: {bluegoo: false, shield: true },
            nextText: 3
        },
        {
        text: "Ignore the merchant.",
            nextText: 3
        },
    
]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "After leaving the merchant you start to feel tired ans tumble upon a small town next to a dangerous looking castle.",
        options: [
            {
                text: "Explore the castle.",
                nextText: 4
            },
            {
                text: "Find a room to sleep at in the towwn.",
                nextText: 5
            },
            {
                text: "Find some hay in a stable to sleep in.",
                nextText: 6
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "You are so tired that you fall asleep while exploring the castle and are killed by some terrible monster in your sleep.",
        options [
            {
                text: "Restart",
                nextText: -1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        text: 'Without any money to buy a room you break into the nearest inn and fall asleep. After a few hours of sleep the owner of the inn finds you and has the town guard lock you in a cell.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Restart',
            nextText: -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        text: 'You wake up well rested and full of energy ready to explore the nearby castle.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Explore the castle',
            nextText: 7
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        text: 'While exploring the castle you come across a horrible monster in your path.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Try to run',
            nextText: 8
          },
          {
            text: 'Attack it with your sword',
            requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.sword,
            nextText: 9
          },
          {
            text: 'Hide behind your shield',
            requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.shield,
            nextText: 10
          },
          {
            text: 'Throw the blue goo at it',
            requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.blueGoo,
            nextText: 11
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        text: 'Your attempts to run are in vain and the monster easily catches.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Restart',
            nextText: -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        text: 'You foolishly thought this monster could be slain with a single sword.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Restart',
            nextText: -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        text: 'The monster laughed as you hid behind your shield and ate you.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Restart',
            nextText: -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        text: 'You threw your jar of goo at the monster and it exploded. After the dust settled you saw the monster was destroyed. Seeing your victory you decide to claim this castle as your and live out the rest of your days there.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Congratulations. Play Again.',
            nextText: -1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    
    startGame()
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Gotham Rounded;
}

body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #333;
}

.container{
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
}
.btn-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,  auto);
    gap: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn{
    background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 50%);
    border: 1px solid hsl(200, 100%, 30%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
}

.btn:hover{
    border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Sawyer's Dungeons and Dragons Game</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="game.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="text">Text</div>
        <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
            <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
            <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
            <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
            <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    
      
    </body>
</html>
```

I appreciate anyone taking a look at  this.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code

**1st:**
You are missing `:` here

```
{
    id: 4,
    text: "You are so tired that you fall asleep while exploring the castle and are killed by some terrible monster in your sleep.",
   // : is missing after options
    options [
        {
            text: "Restart",
            nextText: -1
        }
    ]
},
```

**2nd:**

It should be Object.assign and **NOT**

`state = object.assign(state, option.setState)`

```
 function selectOption(option) {
    const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
  
    // It should be Object.assign
    state = object.assign(state, option.setState)

    if (nextTextNodeId <= 0){
        return startGame()
    }
    state = Object.assign(state, option.State)
    showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}
```

You should add `defer` attribute while linking js file in html file in this case

```
<script defer src="game.js"></script>
```

This should fix the problem

**HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Sawyer's Dungeons and Dragons Game</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        // need to add defer attribute
        <script defer src="game.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="text">Text</div>
        <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
            <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
            <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
            <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
            <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
       
      
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS File**

```
const textElement = document.getElementById("text")
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById("option-buttons")


let state = {}

function startGame(){

    state = {}
    showTextNode(1)

}

function showTextNode(textNodeIndex){
    const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex)
    textElement.innerText = textNode.text
    while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild){
        optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
    }

    textNode.options.forEach(option => {
        if(showOption(option)){
            const button = document.createElement("button")
            button.innerText = option.text
            button.classList.add("btn")
            button.addEventListener("click", () => selectOption(option))
            optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button)

        }
    })
}

function showOption(option) {
    return option.requiredState == null || option.requiredState(state)
}


function selectOption(option) {
    const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
    state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
    if (nextTextNodeId <= 0){
        return startGame()
    }
    state = Object.assign(state, option.State)
    showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}

const textNodes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "You wake up in a strange place and you see a jar of blue goo near you.",
        options: [
            {
                text: "Take goo",
                setState: {bluegoo: true},
                nextText: 2
            },
            {
                text: "Leave the goo",
                nextText: 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "You venture forth in search of answers to where you are when you come across a merchant.",
        options:[ 
            {
                text: "Trade the goo for a sword.",
                requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.bluegoo,
                setState: {bluegoo: false, sword: true },
                nextText: 3
        },
        {
            text: "Trade the goo for a shield.",
            requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.bluegoo,
            setState: {bluegoo: false, shield: true },
            nextText: 3
        },
        {
        text: "Ignore the merchant.",
            nextText: 3
        },
    
]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "After leaving the merchant you start to feel tired ans tumble upon a small town next to a dangerous looking castle.",
        options: [
            {
                text: "Explore the castle.",
                nextText: 4
            },
            {
                text: "Find a room to sleep at in the towwn.",
                nextText: 5
            },
            {
                text: "Find some hay in a stable to sleep in.",
                nextText: 6
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "You are so tired that you fall asleep while exploring the castle and are killed by some terrible monster in your sleep.",
        options: [
            {
                text: "Restart",
                nextText: -1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        text: 'Without any money to buy a room you break into the nearest inn and fall asleep. After a few hours of sleep the owner of the inn finds you and has the town guard lock you in a cell.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Restart',
            nextText: -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        text: 'You wake up well rested and full of energy ready to explore the nearby castle.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Explore the castle',
            nextText: 7
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        text: 'While exploring the castle you come across a horrible monster in your path.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Try to run',
            nextText: 8
          },
          {
            text: 'Attack it with your sword',
            requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.sword,
            nextText: 9
          },
          {
            text: 'Hide behind your shield',
            requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.shield,
            nextText: 10
          },
          {
            text: 'Throw the blue goo at it',
            requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.blueGoo,
            nextText: 11
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        text: 'Your attempts to run are in vain and the monster easily catches.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Restart',
            nextText: -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        text: 'You foolishly thought this monster could be slain with a single sword.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Restart',
            nextText: -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        text: 'The monster laughed as you hid behind your shield and ate you.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Restart',
            nextText: -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        text: 'You threw your jar of goo at the monster and it exploded. After the dust settled you saw the monster was destroyed. Seeing your victory you decide to claim this castle as your and live out the rest of your days there.',
        options: [
          {
            text: 'Congratulations. Play Again.',
            nextText: -1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    
    startGame()
```

Comment: I will try that now and see if that fixes it. I will let you know!

Comment: I fixed the colon where you suggested but this didn't do anything. I've noticed that when I reference JS into an html file it doesn't work on my computer. But if I hard code my JS into the body of the html file it often does work. Don't know if that would help at all.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: showTextNode file:///C:/Users/matti/Documents/JavaScript_Adventure/game.js:16
    startGame file:///C:/Users/matti/Documents/JavaScript_Adventure/game.js:10
    <anonymous> file:///C:/Users/matti/Documents/JavaScript_Adventure/game.js:202

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: textElement is null

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you so much for the help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Can I give you some sort of award on this platform to help your reputation or anything?@Apratim Mahata

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened your browser's console to check for errors?

```
text: "You are so tired that you fall asleep while exploring the castle and are killed by some terrible monster in your sleep.",
options [
```

You are missing a ":" here:

```
options: [
```

As for this:

`state = object.assign(state, option.setState)`

What is `object`?

Comment: I haven't tried that. I will do that now. Thank you.

Comment: So I've looked and I'm not sure what object. Perhaps game state? I'm a python enthusiast and new to Javascript.